# Fast way to find matching elements in multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find matching elements in a large number of large numpy arrays. The way I am doing this currently (holding the arrays in a dictionary and looping over them several times) is very slow, and am looking for a faster way to tackle the problem.

Here is a self-contained section of code that presents the problem:

```
import numpy as np

data = {}
for frame in xrange(100):
    data[frame] = np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 3))
# data structure is 100 'pages' each containing an array of 100 elements
# trying to find matching elements from arrays on different pages

for page in data:
    for point in data[page]:
        for page_to_match in data:
            if page_to_match == page: # exclude matches on the same page
                pass
            else:
                for point_to_match in data[page_to_match]:
                    if np.array_equal(point, point_to_match):
                        print 'Found a match -', point, '- pages:', page, page_to_match
                        # should find about 0 - 3 matches per page
```

As you can see it works but very poorly.

Edit: here is a minimal version of the code. It works quickly for small arrays like this but slowly for large arrays like above. Replace the first three lines in the above section with the following:

```
data = {}
data[0] = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
data[1] = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
data[2] = np.array([[3,4],[5,8]])
```

Comment: Can you define exactly what you want?

Comment: Could you add a minimal sample case?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What I want is to identify matches between the pages for further processing

Comment: @JohnCrow No, I mean a precise specification of your requirements. I don't need you to repeat what you already stated in the question. Using your example, give expected *output*.

Comment: @Divakar I've added a new dictionary which you can use which works quickly, the issue being it is very slow with larger/more arrays.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The output I want is what it is currently doing, it is just far too slow on large datasets, so I am looking for a more efficient solution than the for-loops.

Comment: Would all arrays in that dictionary be of the same shape?

Comment: So you want matching *rows*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Divakar Not necessarily, there could be a different number of rows but same number of columns (i.e `array.shape = (XL, 3L)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If memory isn't an issue, I would solve the problem like this:

```
>>> data = {}
>>> for frame in range(100):
...     data[frame] = np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 3))
...
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> grouper = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in data.items():
...     for row in v:
...         grouper[tuple(row)].append(k)
...
>>> for k, v in grouper.items():
...     if len(v) > 1:
...         print("Duplicate row", np.array(k), "found in pages:")
...         print(*v)
...
```

Results:

```
Duplicate row [89 50 83] found in pages:
13 96
Duplicate row [76 88 29] found in pages:
32 56
Duplicate row [74 26 81] found in pages:
11 99
Duplicate row [19  4 53] found in pages:
17 44
Duplicate row [56 20  4] found in pages:
41 91
Duplicate row [92 62 50] found in pages:
6 45
Duplicate row [86  9 39] found in pages:
12 62
Duplicate row [64 47 84] found in pages:
5 51
Duplicate row [52 74 44] found in pages:
9 19
Duplicate row [60 21 39] found in pages:
14 47
Duplicate row [80 42 33] found in pages:
65 82
Duplicate row [ 4 63 85] found in pages:
8 24
Duplicate row [70 84 35] found in pages:
42 69
Duplicate row [54 14 31] found in pages:
43 47
Duplicate row [38 81 38] found in pages:
51 67
Duplicate row [55 59 10] found in pages:
29 54
Duplicate row [84 77 37] found in pages:
51 53
Duplicate row [76 27 54] found in pages:
33 39
Duplicate row [52 64 20] found in pages:
1 37
Duplicate row [65 97 45] found in pages:
61 80
Duplicate row [69 52  8] found in pages:
60 85
Duplicate row [51  2 37] found in pages:
1 52
Duplicate row [31 36 53] found in pages:
50 84
Duplicate row [24 57  1] found in pages:
34 88
Duplicate row [87 89  0] found in pages:
11 78
Duplicate row [94 38 17] found in pages:
40 89
Duplicate row [46 25 46] found in pages:
54 87
Duplicate row [34 15 14] found in pages:
11 92
Duplicate row [ 3 68  1] found in pages:
48 78
Duplicate row [ 9 17 21] found in pages:
21 62
Duplicate row [17 73 66] found in pages:
1 60
Duplicate row [42 15 24] found in pages:
39 78
Duplicate row [90  8 95] found in pages:
41 61
Duplicate row [19  0 51] found in pages:
30 43
Duplicate row [65 99 51] found in pages:
57 81
Duplicate row [ 5 79 61] found in pages:
17 80
Duplicate row [49 74 71] found in pages:
0 57
Duplicate row [77  3  3] found in pages:
18 57
Duplicate row [37 54 66] found in pages:
5 13
Duplicate row [64 64 82] found in pages:
19 23
Duplicate row [64  6 21] found in pages:
27 39
Duplicate row [39 92 82] found in pages:
8 98
Duplicate row [99 10 15] found in pages:
39 68
Duplicate row [45 16 57] found in pages:
8 53
Duplicate row [12 62 98] found in pages:
29 96
Duplicate row [78 73 56] found in pages:
3 79
Duplicate row [62 87 18] found in pages:
84 97
Duplicate row [46 72 87] found in pages:
5 10
Duplicate row [27 75 25] found in pages:
50 57
Duplicate row [92 62 38] found in pages:
0 87
Duplicate row [27 95 86] found in pages:
15 80
```

Note, my solution is written in Python 3. You should use `d.iteritems()` instead of `d.items()`.

There might be a better solution using `numpy`, but this is quick and works in linear rather than polynomial time.

Comment: Wow that is so much faster, cheers. Just to note that in python 2.7 you also need `from collections import defaultdict` rather than `from itertools import defaultdict` (at least I did)

Comment: @JohnCrow HAH yeah. That is my mistake. I think I copied the wrong line from my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to accelerate your code it seems to be very well suited for [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html). Pythons for loop has some overhead and depending on what you are comparing you may not need rich comparisons. This gives some great potential for acceleration.
In Cython you can compile your slightly modified Python code, so your loops run as fast as native C loops.
Here is a little example:

```
cdef int i, I
cdef int x[1000]
i, I = 0, 1000
for i in range(1000):
    x[i] = i
```

When compiled with Cython, first C code is generated from the Cython-Code. Then it can be executed highly accelerated in comparison to pure Python.

Comment: This likely won't solve the problem of asymptotic behavior - the OPs solution is polynomial time. That quickly dwarfs the differences between Python loops and C-loops.